# How to test toast messages in Appium Test Case?

Tags: android, appium

I know appium does not support testing of toast messages so far but if anyone has use any out of the box solution to for testing toast messages then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **UIAutomator does not detect toast messages** displayed in the Android app app internally finds element using UIAutomator only.

And its difficult to verify toast message through image recognition also because toast messages usually disappear after 1-2 seconds.

We can expect this feature in future android SDK UIAutomator version.

Answer (score 0):

I used OCR technology to test the toast messages. As such you cann't play with toast messsages.

Here is the steps to verify toast messages:

1) Take a screenshot which containing toast message
2) Extract the text from that image using Java OCR
3) Now you can verify that extracted text contains message that is written on toast.